# -1001 error in OpenCL with Nvidia card in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, opencl

I am trying to run [this OpenCL Example](http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/) in Ubuntu 10.04. 
My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 480. I have installed the latest NVIDIA driver and CUDA toolkit manually.

The program compiles without any errors. Thus linking with libOpenCL works. The application also runs but the output is very strange (mostly zeros and some random numbers). Debugging shows that

```
clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
```

returns -1001.

google and stack told me that the reason may be a missing nvidia.icd in /etc/OpenCL/vendors. It was not there so I've added /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd with the following line

```
libnvidia-opencl.so.1
```

I have also tried some variants (absolute paths etc). But nothing solved the problem. Right now I have no idea what else I can try. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have installed the Intel OpenCL SDK and I have copied its icd into /etc/OpenCL/vendors and the application works fine for

```
clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1,
        &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
```

For

```
clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1,
        &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
```

I get the error -1.

EDIT:

I have noticed one thing in the console when executing the application. After execution of line

```
cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
```

the application gives me the output

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_331_uvm'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_331_uvm': Function not implemented
```

There seems to be a conflict with an older driver version since I am using 340.

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.32  Tue Aug  5 20:58:26 PDT 2014
```

Maybe I should try to remove Ubuntu's own NVIDIA drivers one more time and reinstall the latest manually one more time?

EDIT:

The old driver was the problem. Somehow it wasn't removed properly thus I have done it one more time with

```
apt-get remove nvidia-331 nvidia-opencl-icd-331 nvidia-libopencl1-331
```

and now it works. I hope this helps someone who has similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above mentioned problems occurred due to a driver conflict. If you have a similar problem then read the above edits to get the solution.

Comment: Or, you could have simply given it what it asked for: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-uvm` ;)

Comment: Damn. You are right. I haven't seen the *331-uvm stuff :) But since it works with 340 everything is fine now ;)